# Iptables REDIRECT rule has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, iptables, odoo

I have a VPS which is accessible via `hello.com`, running ubuntu and a minimal Python script that serves some html content. The python script is listening on port `8069`. `hello.com:8069` works as expected, but I also need to access the Python script from port `hello.com:80`.

I've done some research, and apparently listening on ports under 1000 is only possible with root, which isn't an option for security reasons. The only real solution I've found is iptables port redirecting.

I've attempted to set up a REDIRECT rule in the nat table, but visiting `hello.com:80` still gives me a timeout error.

Here's my `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8069
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8069 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

I've follow a few guides, and set `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1` and `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Is there something I'm missing?

Server details:

```
root@hello.com:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

root@hello.com:/# iptables -V
iptables v1.4.21

root@hello.com:/# ufw version
ufw 0.34~rc-0ubuntu2
Copyright 2008-2012 Canonical Ltd.

root@hello.com:/# netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0      2067      0      0 0          1879      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        65536 0       637      0      0 0           637      0      0      0 LRU
```

Comment: This is pretty basic but... did you apply your new rule? what's the output of `iptables -S` and/or `iptables -L`?

Comment: I've done a `/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload`, and rebooted with no luck :-( [here's the output of iptables -S](http://pastebin.com/i5wrrXSU)

Comment: the rule looks fine, you're not testing from the very machine with the rule applied, right?

Comment: nope testing from my home pc. could it be a SELinux flag or something like that?

Comment: selinux? your box looks like a debian/ubuntu one to me, correct? Have you checked that your VPS provides doesn't setup an extra firewall?

Comment: Turns out I was approaching this from the wrong direction - we ended up using Nginx to reverse proxy `0.0.0.0:80` -> `localhost:8069`